# How can I enable the developer resources for an account to create certificate if it is created with individual enrollment

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I have enrolled my apple account with Individual-based. Now I can't able to create the certificate under this account. It showing the popup as you don't have access to create this in the certificate and profiles.

Can I able to switch to the Organization account within the same account.

Comment: You can't create certificate with this account. You can only manage you app store and other details on the basis of access given by account holder or admin.

Comment: I have this account and paid for this. Can i able to reclaim this

Comment: I have some doubts on your question. Can you please tell me, what are the steps you have done to generate developer or distribution certificate?

Comment: 1. Click on the certificates profile and click on the + icon https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/     2. Then select any certificates you need to create. (For distribution or development)  3. Select your wish. 4. Generate a manual file in your CSR file machine  4. Drag and drop in the place and then proceed you can able to create that file.

Comment: Yes you did perfectly. Thats the way to create certificates. The issue you mentioned, that does't matter wether its Individuals or Organization Account.

Comment: @A.H.Nuri I have two apple account. One with Organization enrollment and another one with Individual enrollment

Comment: Can I able to generate certificates for individual enrollment  is my question.

Comment: You mean under your Organization account you create child account? If so, you can't create with child account.

Comment: @A.H.Nuri No I have two different apple account. There is no link for both account. Unfortunately I have enrolled the development program with individual. Can I able to move this for organizathion and can I able to create certificate with this?

Comment: Did u get my question or not

Comment: Kindly refer my question.

Comment: Yes I got your point perfectly. Still you can create certificate with Both types of account.

Comment: But the Profile section not showing the +icon

Comment: How long it takes to enable developer resources after enrollment process is completed for individual enroll

Comment: I don't have idea about Account activation. You can contact apple developer team directly. https://developer.apple.com/contact/#!/topic/select/SC1102/subtopic/select